# Unable to convert IP address in Pandas column to latlng (Latitude Longitude)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude, geocode

I am trying to convert data in a Pandas column (containing IP address in each row) to latitude and longitude. Below are my codes:

```
import geocoder

d = pd.DataFrame({'ip_address' : ['49.206.217.180', '200.8.245.246', '186.188.35.217']})

d['coordinate'] = d.apply(geocoder.ip(d['ip_address'].latlng))
```

After running these codes I got an error

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'latlng'

I am not sure why it does that. Could anyone provide me some feedbacks here? Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import geocoder

d = pd.DataFrame({'ip_address' : ['49.206.217.180', '200.8.245.246', '186.188.35.217']})
d['coordinate'] = d['ip_address'].apply(lambda x: geocoder.ip(x).latlng)
```